# AWS system manager RUN command getting timeout

Tags: aws-ssm

Team,

I've created role with `SSMFullaccess` and assigned the same to the newly created amazon linux 2 instances (Where the SSM agent is running and able to ssh). Afterwards, When I try to execute Run command, it's kept throwing the "Timeout" Error.

The instance is in private subnets necessary VPC endpoints are in place. Also, port 80 is opened for the Instance SG. Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: If this is ap-south-1, I am also facing the same issue. It's been ongoing since late November. The logs in `/var/log/amazon/ssm` says there was a i/o timeout sending a request to `https://ssm.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`. I can `ping ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` but not `ssm.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Am using ```us-east-1``.